# mysql arithmetik operation (subtraction) last - first of the day(week, month)

Tags: mysql, sql, math, subtraction

i got a MySQL tbl, with some colums, where every 5 min. a new row is inserted with 3 values

```
1. Auto inc. curent Date Unix timestamp --> date
2. power consumption absolut --> wert01
3. Power Generation absolut --> wert02
```

To Show this Information in a Graph, for Exampl for weekly power consumption, i need to select the First and the last, which allready Works, but then have to Substract the last from the First and Show only tue result & the day of the werk.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT wert01
   FROM sml_splitt
   WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
     AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS 'last',

  (SELECT wert01
   FROM sml_splitt
   WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
     AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY
   ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) AS 'lirst
```

I am searching for some days to find a solution, but with no success.
Hopfuly, you could help me.

Comment: Will a query that returns the average by date be of use to you?

Comment: no, not realy... thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with your query, then you can do the math by nesting it one more time like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/515ef/1

```
select t1.last, t1.first, t1.last - t1.first as result
from (
  select (
    select wert01
    from sml_splitt
    where dt >= curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate()) + 6 day
    and dt < curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate()) day
    order by dt desc limit 1
  ) as 'last',
  (
    select wert01
    from sml_splitt
    where dt >= curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate()) + 6 day
    and dt < curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate()) day
    order by dt limit 1
  ) as 'first'
) t1
;
```

If you really want to work with this data by week for reporting purposes, let me suggest a couple of views. The first will give you all of your distinct beginning of week dates:

```
create view v1 as
select date(dt) as week_begins
from sml_splitt
where dayofweek(dt) = 1
group by week_begins
```

The second view joins the first view with itself to give you a week beginning and week ending range:

```
create view v2 as
select t1.week_begins, coalesce(t2.week_begins,now()) as week_ends
from v1 t1
left join v1 t2
on t2.week_begins = t1.week_begins + interval 7 day
```

You can see the results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d1b3/2. Notice that I'm using `now()` to get the current date and time if the week hasn't ended yet.

From there you can join your view with your original table and use `min()` and `max()` function with grouping to get the starting and ending 'wert' values and do any calculations on them that you like.

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d1b3/6

```
select week_begins, week_ends,
min(wert01) as start_wert01,
max(wert01) as end_wert01,
max(wert01) - min(wert01) as power_consumed,
min(wert02) as start_wert02,
max(wert02) as end_wert02,
max(wert02) - min(wert02) as power_generated,
(max(wert02) - min(wert02)) - (max(wert01) - min(wert01)) as net_generated
from v2
inner join sml_splitt
on sml_splitt.dt >= v2.week_begins
and sml_splitt.dt < v2.week_ends
group by week_begins
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, very much... the first and second solution working for me!

Comment: @SaschaSchmitt That's great. If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted.